bash: /usr/local/bin/minikube: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
I am using lima on macOS with arm64 architecture (M3 Chip).
I installed minikube with the following package: https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-darwin-arm64
When I am trying to start minikube, it's giving me the following error:
bash: /usr/local/bin/minikube: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

When using sudo:
/usr/local/bin/minikube: 1: ????
p: not found
/usr/local/bin/minikube: 4: Syntax error: ")"

Image
I tried several times to install it.
I tried to use amd64 but it did not work either.

What does arch print in your terminal? It's possible that you've configured your terminal to run using Rosetta.

The checkbox 'Open using Rosetta' is unchecked, but I executed the following command when installing lima:
limactl start --vm-type=vz --rosetta
(Reference: https://lima-vm.io/docs/config/multi-arch/)

Can't reproduce. The file you linked works fine on arm64 macOS. Whatever you have at /usr/local/bin/minikube is not that.

@Siguza I tried to remove /usr/local/bin/minimize and install it from scratch, it did not work. I think it’s related some how to Rosetta

@JoachimSauer said it

Wait wait wait... are you trying to run a macOS binary inside a Linux VM?!
